# How to check if VBA module has been modified?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel workbook that I would like to export the code for every time the workbook is closed but I would like to do so selectively so that each module will only get exported if it has been modified since the workbook was opened. I would like to be able to use the exported files to run a diff on the code and I'm assuming that re-exporting every time will cause the files to always be flagged as different. Here's an attempt at some pseudo-code to show what I mean:

```
for each module in Workbook
    if module.isModified() then
        module.export
    end if
next module
```

Comment: If you can use the phrase `pseudo code`, you're capable of an attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBComponent has a readonly property. Add reference to [VBE](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx) and you should be able to access "changed" VBComponents

bool Saved

[Saved Property - (Excel 2003 VBA Programmer's Reference Google Books)](https://books.google.co.za/books?id=gkPLT_hBHjMC&pg=PA981&lpg=PA981&dq=VBComponent%20saved&source=bl&ots=qyBsmsjmGn&sig=W5fjUtH4LGtHEJhKY0xOYve1FTE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAmoVChMI4M3NuO_0yAIVgXUeCh2rfQ8h#v=onepage&q=VBComponent%20saved&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

I was just being lazy about it and hoping someone already new a method that I hadn't found. Sorry about that.

I found that I can use the following.

```
for each module in Workbook
    if not module.saved then
        module.export
    end if
next module
```

Then, I'll just run the export function every time the workbook is saved.